# Binding Redirect for a dependency dll

Tags: c#, .net, assembly-binding-redirect

i have a project, that uses GodSharp.Opc.Ua.Client. This nuget package depends on OPCFoundation.Netstandart.Opc.Ua.Core, which in turn depends on Newtonsoft v.13.0.3.
My project has to be integrated in a larger project as dll.
That larger project depends on Newtonsoft.Json v.12.0.3  and can absolutely not be updated at this point.
As i understand it, i should be able to solve this with a binding redirect, as soon as come to a point where anything from Opc.Ua.Core is used, i get the exception that

```
        +       e   {"Die Datei oder Assembly \"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed\" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden.":"Newtonsoft.Json, Version=13.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed"} System.Exception {System.IO.FileNotFoundException}
```

My binding redirect looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Memory" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.1.2" newVersion="4.0.1.2" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Opc.Ua.Client" publicKeyToken="bfa7a73c5cf4b6e8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.372.0" newVersion="1.5.372.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Opc.Ua.Configuration" publicKeyToken="bfa7a73c5cf4b6e8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.372.0" newVersion="1.5.372.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Opc.Ua.Security.Certificates" publicKeyToken="bfa7a73c5cf4b6e8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.373.0" newVersion="1.5.373.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3.0" newVersion="12.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Opc.Ua.Core" publicKeyToken="bfa7a73c5cf4b6e8" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.4.372.0" newVersion="1.4.372.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions" publicKeyToken="adb9793829ddae60" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.4" newVersion="6.0.0.4" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I don't understand what i am doing wrong. Please help.

As sugested by J.Memisevic i regenerated my binding redirects and that solved the conflict with Newtonsoft.Json versions.

Now i get another error, but only when i integrate my usercontrol in an other project.

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Memory, 
Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Memory, 
Version=4.0.1.1, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Memory, Version=4.0.1.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

System.IO.FileLoadException: "Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)"

Die Datei oder Assembly "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" oder eine Abhängigkeit davon wurde nicht gefunden. 
Die gefundene Manifestdefinition der Assembly stimmt nicht mit dem Assemblyverweis überein. 
(Ausnahme von HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I'm sorry that this is in german.

The error occures the first time i use an element from GodSharp.Opc.Ua.Client

When i put my usercontrol inside a simple window, this error does not occure.
I removed System.Memory and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe via nuget package manager from my project. The error still occurs.

Comment: Try to regenerate your binding redirects and then reduce the newVersion value.

Comment: Regenerating the redirects got me a little farther. It seems Newtonsoft works now. 
Unfortunately now i get another error. Do i add that to my original question or start a new question?

Comment: add it here , I think it is ok

Comment: what do you mean by integrating in another project ? Does that project have binding redirects also ?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. The project i'm integrating my project into is in c++/Cli . I should mention that there are already multiple c# projects integrated in the c++/Cli project.

Comment: Which version of System.Memory and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe do you have installed in your project ?

Comment: System.Memory 4.5.5 and System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe 6.0.0.0
I also tried earlier versions.

Comment: In your binding redirects - are those redirects generated with those exact versions ?

Comment: For System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe yes, System.Memory is generated with 4.0.1.2. But that seems to be the version that is used in the nuget package v 4.5.5

Comment: Try to manually update the for System.Memory  to be   <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.5.5.0" newVersion="4.5.5.0" />

Comment: I tried that. There was no change

Comment: i also tried adding System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe to the GAC as sugested here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1302681/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-com